# I can't open decompilers? (jar)

Tags: java, jar, path

I'm looking for good decompilers that support java 8. I've cfr and procyon but the decompilers both won't open (.jar file).

I did assign environment variables JAVA_HOME and PATH...
I can open any other jar file though.

I've tried http://www.javadecompilers.com/ but it fails to decompile alot.

Comment: Are you trying to open a heavily obfuscated jar ?

Comment: You could use the decompiler built into IntelliJ, https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower This works well with lambdas for example.

Comment: @Xvolks I'm trying to open the decompiler itself.

Comment: @PeterLawrey IntelliJ doesnt show anything when I click the .class file I want to decompile

Comment: @SJacobs maybe it is the problem: the file is already locked by the system when you open it. Try to make a copy of the jar elsewhere.

Comment: @Xvolks I'm not sure what you mean, if I copy & paste the file elsewhere it doesn't change anything. The decompiler I'm trying to run is the last jar version from https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/downloads

Comment: You should be able to use `javap` to read the class, even if it has a been obfuscated.

Comment: `java -jar procyon-decompiler-0.5.30.jar procyon-decompiler-0.5.30.jar` just works here under OSX 10.11

Comment: @Xvolks ah it works with batch file, thanks didn't know that. How would I go about decompiling a single class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should launch procyon without arguments to display all possible options.
I cannot explain each of them in comments.

`java -jar procyon-decompiler-0.5.30.jar`

Comment: Thank you so much this decompiler is great!